# Constructing a class inside another class( a non static member reference must be relative to a specific object)

Tags: c++, class, static, nested

I have class **A** which has a vector of pointers to class **B** as its member variable. The class **B** is only going to be used inside **A** so I decided to define it inside **A**. The constructor for **B** uses a variable that is calculated inside **A**'s constructor, lets call that **c**.

The problem is, in *A.cpp* when I write:

```
A::B::B(...)
{
foo(c);
}
```

It gives me the error: *a non static member reference must be relative to a specific object*

I tried **A::c** instead of **c**, but that didn't solve the problem. Guess what I want is, having a way of B inheriting variables from A without actually being its child, if that makes any sense. Anyway of accomplishing it with generalized version of "*this*" or something like that?

Comment: Pass it as a parameter to B's constructor from whatever code in `A::A()` is generating it.

Comment: Do i really have to? :/ there are going to be three such c's and B's constructor is going to be called many times...

Comment: Why don't you post some minimal code that illustrates and reproduces the problem?

Comment: I don't really see the point. Do you want to make suggestions for changing the design?

Comment: Guess what I want is, having a way of B inheriting variables from A without actually being its child. Anyway of accomplishing it with generalized version of "this" or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B has no way of knowing which c you are referring to.  You can make it work like this easily though by passing a pointer to this when you construct B.

```
class A {
    class B {
        B(A * owner) : 
        owner(owner) {}
        void doSomething() {
            int d = owner->c;
        }
    private:
        A * owner;
    };

    A() :
    bInstance(this) {}

    int c; 
private:
    B bInstance;
};
```

I don't think there's anything built into the language to solve your problem.